# Unable to disable Hyper-V in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

Hi I installed Docker for Windows which enabled Hyper-V on my windows 10 machine.
Unfortunately this caused Virtual Box to not work anymore, therefore I removed Docker again, but Hyper-V is still activated.

If I try to disable Hyper-V with any of those ways:
http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/ on the reboot it will first try to apply the changes and than say that the changes couldn't be applied and reverts, so Hyper-V is activated again.

Has anybody an idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: No error with any of the methods? Did you check your Eventlog for hints what the error could be? What error(s) did you get from Virtual Box?

Comment: Virtual Box gives me a bluescreen whenever I try to boot a vm. Will try to find some error logs

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\logs\cbs to the desktop, zip the folder and share the zip (onedrive). I'll try to help you

Comment: @magicandre1981 from the VM or his host?

Comment: from the system where you try to remove Hyper-V and get the "reverting changes" message after reboot

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy906argjlqj8hh/CBS.zip?dl=0 here you go

Comment: "00000193 (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: Network Drivers ". I also need the files **C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log** and **C:\Windows\winsxs\poqexec.log**

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/36awvgmr6f1dpmz/win_logs.zip?dl=0

Comment: I see errors related to the virtualbox driver file **VBoxNetAdp6.inf** Remove Virtualbox also completely (make sure no drivers are left after uninstall VB) before trying to remove Hyper-V

Comment: Removed Vbox + drivers + registry entries. Sadly had no effect. Still thanks for trying to help

Comment: @Jakob Abfalter - Thanks for posting this question. I was debating on whether to install this on my machine, your experience has made my decision crystal clear.

Answer (score 25):

For others who have the same problem, but cant find a solution yet:

Probably you have some leftover internet adapters on your machine.
(sometimes, they are disabled and not visible in the Hyper-V manager)

Go to your Network Center and see if you still have network adapters
from the 'Hyper-V' kind. (you cant remove/delete them on right click)

To still get them off your system, go to:
Properties > Configure > Driver Software (tab)

From there, choose 'Remove device'. Wait a little, and press F5 (refresh).
Repeat this process until all network adapters of Hyper-V are gone.

Now try and uninstall Hyper-V again and see it work.
(reason previous uninstall failure: unable to cleanly uninstall hyper-v, due uncontrolled dependencies)

Comment: Minor point: Under Windows 10, it's not 'Remove device' but 'Uninstall Device'.  Same effect, though, and everything else works as printed on the box.

Comment: Give this man a cookie!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Remove all Hyper-V virtual network adapters/switches before disabling Hyper-V from optional features.

To remove virtual switches you setup use the appropriate dialog:

[image: How to remove switches]

Comment: Could you expand on it a bit? If you include some more information and how you came up with that solution it would certainly improve this answer.

Comment: @Seth I don't know if this answer is correct or not, but here is how you should remove switches: You need to open Hyper-V Manager and then do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4cHJ.png.

Comment: You uploaded that picture and made an edit. Why not just include the picture in the post?

Comment: So I am to believe that the reason the author was unable to remove Hyper-V is because they had a virtual Hyper-V network adapator installed?  How did you conclude the author even has a virtual switch configured?

Comment: I'm saying that might be the solution, because in my case this turns out to be the problem. I actually had the virtual switches screwed up across insider preview updates, unable to find them in virtual switch configuration, so I had to uninstall them in device manager.

Comment: I had the same problem because I disabled the network interface in the network and sharing center (the adapter was renamed as broken)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I could not install Intel(r) HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager). I opened PowerShell in Administrator mode and ran this command: 
    **Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All**

for more info http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have inadvertently disabled a Hyper-V virtual switch in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections. If so, try removing it from device manager then disable Hyper-V.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already solved this problem by freshly installing Windows